# DSLR-like image review on Nikon Z 6II?

Tags: nikon, camera-settings, nikon-z6

Is there a way to make image review only show on the monitor when shooting using the viewfinder on a Nikon Z6 II? I want to shoot as if it's a DSLR, that is: take a picture using the viewfinder, then automatically see the picture on the monitor (if I take my eye away from the viewfinder).

I have it in "prioritize viewfinder" mode. If image review is set to "on", I get the image review automatically in the viewfinder, which I do not want. If image review is set to "on (monitor only)", and I take my eye away from the viewfinder immediately after taking a picture, the monitor remains off and I have to press the playback button to see the picture.

Am I missing something here? I would have thought this would be a basic setup that many photographers are used to from DSLR shooting, but I can't find a way to enable it.

Comment: What about [Automatic display switch](https://darrellyoung.com/blog/understanding-the-nikon-z-camera-monitor-modes)?

Comment: @MrUpsidown What about it? Sounds like you may have a possible answer... which probably should not be subverted in the comments, rather than posted as an answer, even if it's fairly short. [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/15871) and [Criteria for determining if a post should be a comment or an answer](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5578/15871)

Comment: @MichaelC it's not an answer. It's a clarification question. If OP confirms this fixes the issue, I will provide it as an answer.

Comment: @MrUpsidown "automatic display switch" mode doesn't help

Comment: @binaryfunt how does it not help? What is the behavior then? Is the eye sensor working correctly? Is the eye cap in its place?

Comment: It doesn't help in that the behaviour is exactly the same as I described for "prioritize viewfinder" mode (apart from the fact that the live view is shown on the monitor when you're not looking through the viewfinder - but that's irrelevant to the question). The eye sensor is working perfectly. What is the eye cap?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can get my Z9 to behave close to what you want is to have the viewfinder display set to automatic display switching with image review set to On (not On- monitor only).

With these settings, after an image is taken it will automatically be displayed for review... initially in the viewfinder, but then switching to on the monitor when you lower the camera from your eye.

I can't find any other combination of settings that will automatically display the image on the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

My wife was just having the same issue with our Z6ii. After reading the above comments, especially regarding the viewfinder cap, I slid our viewfinder cap up, cleaned off all the sand and debris that was in front of the sensor, but the cap back on and everything works perfectly now. In all settings. As they should.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "works perfectly now". Are you saying that when you take a picture, the image does not display in the viewfinder and only displays automatically on the monitor?